# Reconstruct matrix

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to find all elements of a matrix which has only 2 numbers as its elements, given its row and column sums, by using the least amount of element values?

Example 
Matrix A 
    1 1 2 2 
    1 2 1 2 
    2 1 1 2 
    2 2 2 1

Row sum = {6,6,6,7} 
Column sum = {6,6,6,7}

Matrix B 
1 1 2 2 
1 1 2 2 
2 2 1 1 
2 2 1 2

Row sum = {6,6,6,7} 
Column sum = {6,6,6,7}

Is there a way to determine and specify the least amount of element values and their positions along with row and column sums, such that matrix A can be reconstructed (and not matrix B)?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: **Hint:** You have two variables and several linear equations, when can you solve the system of equations?